# How do I obtain the different number of splits from GroupShuffleSplit scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `GroupShuffleSplit`, and I want to get the different number of splits `n_splits=5`.

```
splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.20, n_splits=5, random_state = 3)
split = splitter.split(data, groups=data['ID'])
train_inds, test_inds = next(split)

train = data.iloc[train_inds]
test = data.iloc[test_inds]
```

I don't know how to achieve that. I know I have to use `get_n_splits`, but I am failing to do it for my example.

I can print each split like this:

```
for train_idx, test_idx in splitter.split(data, groups=data['ID']):
    print("TRAIN:", train_idx, "TEST:", test_idx)
```

and I get:

```
TRAIN: [  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  18  19  20  21
  22  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  42  43  44
  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  67  68
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88
  89  90  91  92  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 131 132
 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168
 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188
 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 200 201 202 203 204 205 208 209 210 211
 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 222 223 224 225 230 231 232 233 239 240 241
 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 251 252 253 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262
 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 280 281 282 283 284 291
 292] TEST: [ 14  15  16  17  23  38  39  40  41  61  62  63  64  65  66  69  70  93
  94 118 119 127 128 129 130 178 179 197 198 199 206 207 219 220 221 226
 227 228 229 234 235 236 237 238 249 250 254 275 276 277 278 279 285 286
 287 288 289 290]
TRAIN: [  2   3   4   5  11  12  13  18  19  20  21  22  23  27  28  34  35  38
  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  71  72  73  74  75  76
  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  95  96  97  98
  99 100 101 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166
 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184
 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 197 198 199 200 201 202 203
 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221
 222 223 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245
 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 259 260 261 262 267 268 269
 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292] TEST: [  0   1   6   7   8   9  10  14  15  16  17  24  25  26  29  30  31  32
  33  36  37  69  70  77  78  93  94 102 103 104 105 106 131 132 133 134
 144 145 146 147 148 196 224 225 226 227 228 229 257 258 263 264 265 266
 270 271 272 273 274]
TRAIN: [  0   1   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
  20  21  23  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  45  46
  47  48  49  50  51  52 ...
```

However, I want to save each split in a df or feed it into the model so that I can use each split to train my ML models. Can I achieve such a thing, and if so, how?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To save each split in a df:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

# generate random data
obj_ids = np.arange(300)
group_ids = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=len(obj_ids))
data = pd.DataFrame(zip(obj_ids, group_ids), columns=["id", "group_id"])

splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=0.20, n_splits=5, random_state=3)
for split_idx, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(splitter.split(data, groups=data['group_id'])):
    data[f'split_{split_idx}'] = 0
    data[f'split_{split_idx}'][train_idx] = 1
```

You will get dataframe with additional 5 columns where the `1` denotes a train index; `0` - test index:

```
      id  group_id  split_0  split_1  split_2  split_3  split_4
0      0         8        1        0        1        1        1
1      1         9        1        1        1        0        1
2      2         9        1        1        1        0        1
3      3         3        1        0        1        1        0
4      4         7        1        1        1        1        0
..   ...       ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
295  295         3        1        0        1        1        0
296  296         4        0        1        1        0        1
297  297         8        1        0        1        1        1
298  298         2        1        1        1        1        1
299  299         8        1        0        1        1        1
```